# Searching for records in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to search for records in Microsoft SQL Server manager?

I mean something like in VS pressing <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> and searching by word?

Comment: Press CTRL+T and run your query. Result will output as text, then you can search

Comment: Could you clarify a bit the question? You want to search in the results returned by a query or search all the database for some data? Or you want to search in the table/view/etc. definitions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in searching for objects in SQL Server management studio. There are views and tables that can be used to search for objects like:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '%...%'
```

To search for tables.

If you mean, searching for data within a table, I need to learn T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There are non-free 3rd party tools (ex. Redgate's SQL Search), but I use the proc below. You have to create the proc in every [master] database so it's available server-wide, but you can pass in a search term and an optional database name (otherwise it searches through object definitions in all databases):

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_FindTextOnServer]    Script Date: 10/6/2017 3:39:19 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/*-----------------------------------------------------------
    This procedure will search all or a specified database objects 
    for the supplied text and return a table with the values

    Examples:
        EXEC sp_FindTextOnServer 'Billing', 'fcsCore'
        EXEC sp_FindTextOnServer 'vJurisdiction'

-----------------------------------------------------------*/
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_FindTextOnServer] 
                @text VARCHAR(40),
                @searchDB VARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS 

    DECLARE @DisplayText VARCHAR(100),
            @sSql VARCHAR(1000),
            @line VARCHAR(300), 
            @char CHAR, 
            @lineNo INTEGER, 
            @counter INTEGER, 
            @AddedRecord BIT,       
            @dbObjectType VARCHAR(100),
            @dbObject VARCHAR(100),
            @ObjectBody VARCHAR(7000),
            @dbName VARCHAR(100)

    SET @DisplayText = @Text
    SET @text = '%' + @text + '%' 
    SET @AddedRecord = 0

    CREATE TABLE #SearchResults
    (
        DBName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        ObjectType VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        ObjectName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        Line INT NOT NULL,
        Reference VARCHAR(7000) NOT NULL
    )

    CREATE TABLE #tempSysComments
    (
        DBName VARCHAR(100),
        DBObjectType VARCHAR(100),
        DBObject VARCHAR(100),
        TextString text
    )

    --Populate a table with the search results from all databases on the server that include the searched text
    SET @sSql = 'USE [?]
                SELECT 
                    ''?'' AS DBName,
                    LOWER(REPLACE(o.type_desc, ''_'', '' '')) + '' ('' + RTRIM(type) + '')'' AS DBObjectType, 
                    OBJECT_NAME(sm.object_id) AS DBObject, 
                    CAST(sm.definition AS VARCHAR(7000)) AS TextString
                FROM sys.sql_modules AS sm
                    JOIN sys.objects AS o 
                        ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
                WHERE CAST(sm.definition AS VARCHAR(7000)) LIKE ''' + @text + '''
                ORDER BY o.type_desc, OBJECT_NAME(sm.object_id)'

    IF (@searchDB IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #tempSysComments    
        EXEC sp_MSFOREachDB @sSql
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @sSql = REPLACE(@sSql, '?', @searchDB)
        INSERT INTO #tempSysComments    
        EXEC (@sSql)
    END

    DECLARE codeCursor CURSOR 
    FOR 
        SELECT DBName, DBObjectType, DBObject, TextString
        FROM #tempSysComments
        WHERE DBName IS NOT NULL

    OPEN codeCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM codeCursor INTO @dbName, @dbObjectType, @dbObject, @ObjectBody 

    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 
    BEGIN 
        PRINT 'Text ''' + @DisplayText + ''' was not found in objects on server ' + @@SERVERNAME
        -- Close and release code cursor. 
        CLOSE codeCursor 
        DEALLOCATE codeCursor 
        RETURN 
    END 

    -- Search each object within code cursor. 
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        SET @lineNo = 0 
        SET @counter = 1 

        -- Process each line. 
        WHILE (@counter <> Len(@ObjectBody)) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @char = SUBSTRING(@ObjectBody, @counter,1) 

            -- Check for line breaks. 
            IF (@char = CHAR(13)) 
            BEGIN 
                SET @lineNo = @lineNo + 1 

                -- Check if we found the specified text. 
                IF (PATINDEX(@text, @line) <> 0)
                BEGIN 
                    SET @AddedRecord = 1
                    INSERT #SearchResults
                        SELECT @dbName, @dbObjectType, @dbObject, @lineNo,  LEFT(RTRIM(LTRIM(@line)), 7000)
                END

                SET @line = '' 
            END 

            SET @line = @line + @char 
            SET @counter = @counter + 1 

        END 

        IF (@AddedRecord = 0)
            INSERT #SearchResults
                SELECT @dbName, @dbObjectType, @dbObject, 0, SUBSTRING(@ObjectBody, 1, 7000)

        SET @AddedRecord = 0

        FETCH NEXT FROM codeCursor INTO @dbName, @dbObjectType, @dbObject, @ObjectBody 
    END 

    -- Close and release cursor. 
    CLOSE codeCursor 
    DEALLOCATE codeCursor 

    --  Return the info.
    SELECT DISTINCT DBName, ObjectType, ObjectName, Line, RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(Reference, CHAR(9), '    '), CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), ' '))) AS Reference
    FROM #SearchResults 
    ORDER BY DBName, ObjectType, ObjectName, Line

    --  Cleanup.
    DROP TABLE #SearchResults
    DROP TABLE #tempSysComments

    RETURN
```

Comment: Redgate SQL Search *is* free (and very useful), in fact, I think is the only free tool by Redgate :-). Anyway, I think the OP asks about searching for data in any field of the database.